# Revit API python Error:Exception: idx can be only 0, 1, 2

Tags: revit-api, pyrevit

Can someone help me understand this error.  I'm still learning the Revit API (and python) and searching hasn't helped. I'm trying to get the xyz Location Point of an element.

here is my code:

```
elements= ui.Selection() 
for d in elements:
for l in d.Parameters:
    for x in d.Location.Point:
        print x
```

here is the output, NOTE: it does return three values:

```
149.412934765
69.7704247908
-3.71628688979
```

here is the error message. I don't understand the reference to idx in the error message:

```
IronPython Traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C\BTS-NY-BETA.extension\BTS-NY-BETA.tab\Beta Tools.panel\BETA3.pushbutton\Get linked docs_script.py", line 32, in 
Exception: idx can be only 0, 1, 2.
Parameter name: idx


Script Executor Traceback:
Autodesk.Revit.Exceptions.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: idx can be only 0, 1, 2.
Parameter name: idx

 at Autodesk.Revit.DB.XYZ.get_Item(Int32 idx)
 at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.FuncCallInstruction`3.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
 at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
 at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run4[T0,T1,T2,T3,TRet](T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3)
 at IronPython.Runtime.ItemEnumerator.System.Collections.IEnumerator.MoveNext()
 at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.FuncCallInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
 at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
 at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run2[T0,T1,TRet](T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
 at IronPython.Compiler.PythonScriptCode.RunWorker(CodeContext ctx)
 at PyRevitBaseClasses.ScriptExecutor.ExecuteScript(PyRevitCommandRuntime& pyrvtCmd)
```

Comment: What on line 32 of script `Get linked docs_script.py`?

Answer (score 2):

A Point is not an array of values, accessing X, Y, Z is the right way.

Answer (score 0):

While I still do not understand the error, I was able to eliminate the error message by editing my code as follows:

```
elements= ui.Selection() 
for d in elements:
for l in d.Parameters:
    for pt in d.Location.Point:
        print pt.X
        print pt.Y
        print pt.Z
```

Comment: First of all the location is not guaranteed to be a `Point`. It can also be a `Line` in which case your code would throw an exception. Also, I want to second Matt's comments that you don't have to iterate over the `Point`. To get XYZ values simple call `loc = d.Location.Point` and then `print loc.X` etc. There is no reason to iterate over point properties like that.

Comment: @Matt and Konrad - yes, i see you are right,no question about it, its interesting  that iterating over it gave the results I thought it would and then produced the error

Comment: please make sure to accept Matt's answer. His suggestion is the correct one here.